# get the text from <a> tag and hide it without affecting another tag inside <a> tag

Tags: jquery, text, each, loops

Is there any way to select text from a  tag without affecting any other tag. For example - here is the scenario - Home - when the Page  loads I want to hide the text in the link ie 'HOME' but i want the icon still visible and clickable, so is there any way to do this with jQuery
I have tried this one -

```
$('ul#nav li').each(function(i){
var a = $(this).find('a').text();
});
```

I am getting the text of each a, how can hide that text....

to be more specific here is the exact code what i use - 
    
     Home
    
I want to hide only text, ie 'HOME', i want to keep  icon with in the span as it is, that is my isse

Comment: what is your html? Are you placing icon i.e <img/> tag inslde the anchor tag?

Comment: some thing like this -  <li class="nav-home"> <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span>Home</a></li> - image is the background image of class icon, i want to hide only text HOME not icon

Answer (score 0):

Use `.wrap()` jQuery method that will help.

```
$('ul#nav li').each(function(i){
  var a = $(this).find('a').wrap('<span style="display:none;" />');
});
```

also `.wrapInner()` will also work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('ul#nav li').each(function(i){
            var a = $(this).find('a').wrapInner('<span style="display:none;" />');
        });
    });

</script>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="">asd</a></li>
    <li><a href="">12312</a></li>
    <li><a href="">asdas</a></li>
    <li><a href="">123123123</a></li>
    <li><a href="">asdda56s4da56s4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I expect some thing like this, but the issue is something else, here is the code - <li class="nav-home"> <a href="#"><span class="icon"></span>Home</a></li> - image is the background image of class icon, i want to hide only text HOME not icon

Comment: @user2119035 so just add text-indent:9999px; for anchor link

Comment: it works, if i use text-indent, how can i give animation for  the text to re-appear on hover the icon.

Comment: @SalihK use .hover jQuery method that has two callback function one for hover-over and one for hover-out and inside hove-over use .css to assign css to that dom...

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following to the css of the anchor tag.

```
text-indent: -9999px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give transparent color to anchor. This will hide text.

```
color:transparent
```

You can also use `!important` with style if it doesnt work at first place